# Fetch distinct field values from frozen set column in Cassandra columnfamily

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cassandra-2.0

Hi please help me to get cql query for below requirement
- Column family contains columns: deptid (datatype:uuid emplList (datatype: set frozen(employee) )
How would I get all distinct employees name from employee object where it is stored at set as column value for emplList.

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried and people will be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Such queries couldn't be expressed in the pure CQL - Cassandra is optimized to read data by primary key, and aggregation operations are very limited. You have 2 choices:

1. Read all data from table by your program, and extract distinct values
2. Use Spark with [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) - it will read all the data from table, but you'll have higher level abstraction to work with data, and it could perform more optimized scanning of your table.

Comment: Thank you Alex.. Means,  I can use datastax Java driver to fetch all results as deptid, empllist set.... Then just write a programme to get distinct values from emplList object. Please suggest

Comment: I would warn that effective scan of the Cassandra table not so simple task, so it would be better to stuck with Spark

Comment: OK Sure Alex. Will go with spark